# sql Error in derby - ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "KEY"

Tags: sql, derby

following query gives error like `ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "KEY" at line 1, column 48.`

I am not able to understand what is the exact issue. column `KEY` is exist and datatype is `integer`.

```
Insert into UOM_TYPE 
(UNITS_OF_MEASURE_NO,TYPE,KEY,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,VERSION)
values 
(79,'Clinical Property',32,'JRL',DATE('2007-05-04'),'JRL',DATE('2007-05-04'),2);
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KEY is a Keyword in derby db. you have to escape it :

```
Insert into UOM_TYPE 
(UNITS_OF_MEASURE_NO,TYPE,"KEY",CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,VERSION)
values 
(79,'Clinical Property',32,'JRL',DATE('2007-05-04'),'JRL',DATE('2007-05-04'),2);
```